# SQL query to split table into 3 parts and fetch top 5 among them

Tags: sql

I have a table consisting of `name`, `values`. I want to split this into 3 parts, upper, middle and lower and get the top 5 values in all three. Is there a way to do so?

EDIT 1:
The table having 45 entries for example will look like.

```
name  | value
a1    | v1
a2    | v2
a3    | v3
...
a43   | v43
a44   | v44
a45   | v45
```

And I want a resulting table as

```
name  | value
a1    | v1
a2    | v2
a3    | v3
a4    | v4
a5    | v5
a16   | v16
a17   | v17
a18   | v18
a19   | v19
a20   | v20
a31   | v31
a32   | v32
a33   | v33
a34   | v34
a35   | v35
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by upper, middle and lower?

Comment: @SalmanA Three equal parts of table, Suppose a table has 45 entries then top would have the top 15 entries, middle would have the next 15 and bottom would have the last 15.

Comment: It would help if you provided some sample data (update the question, not in comments) and show exactly what result you want to see.

Comment: @KoenLostrie I have made a dummy example. Have a look.

Comment: OK, which column determines the order of rows (i.e. determines that a1 is the first row and a45 is the last one)?

Comment: All the names have unique values so name is the primary key.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports window functions use `NTILE()` to split the table in as many parts as you want and with `ROW_NUMBER()` keep as many rows as you want from each part:

```
SELECT name, value
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY name) rn
  FROM (
    SELECT *, NTILE(?1) OVER (ORDER BY name) part
    FROM tablename
  ) t  
) t
WHERE rn <= ?2;
```

Change `?1` to the number of parts that you want to split the table and `?2` to the number of rows that you want from each part.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0e5cb7bc278317fb6c571ab734de1a9).